# What will be the time complexity of this piece of code and why?

Tags: time-complexity

The time complexity for the following code is `O(n)`. But why is it?

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j]) {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you wanna try the Computer Science Stackexchange http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @enpenax This question works as well here as it would on CS.  No need to migrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control passes through the outer loop `n` times.

Control passes through the inner loop `n` times at most. That's not `n` times *for each pass through the outer loop,* it's `n` times at most, *total.*